# Automatically re-arrange HTML list base on numeric sort order updates

Tags: javascript, html, list, sorting

I'm building a page where there is a ranked list.  The items in the list are associated with a rank order number.  The order numbers for each item in the list changes as users make different selection choices else where on the page.  I've been looking around to see if there is a way to automatically re-arrange the list items when their rank order number changes.  I've looked at some JQuery **.sort()** examples, those require re-building the DOM element and it does appear that I can apply any animation using those approaches.  I've also looked at JQuery **UI's** sortable, however that seems to only allow sorting by drag and drop.  I'm really looking for something like **Isotope** [Isotope's sorting](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/sorting.html).  However, I'm not able to leverage that framework due to licensing issue.  To add to the challenges, each list item would contain collapsable sections so their size is not fixed.

I've originally envisioned something like this:

```
Initial HTML:
    <ul class="sortedlist">
        <li class="1">A</li>
        <li class="2">B</li>
        <li class="3">C</li>
        <li class="4">D</li>
        <li class="5">E</li>
    </ul>

Browser:
    ---
     A
    ---
     B 
    ---
     C
    ---
     D
    ---
     E
    ---

Updated HTML:
    <ul class="sortedlist">
        <li class="4">A</li>
        <li class="1">B</li>
        <li class="5">C</li>
        <li class="2">D</li>
        <li class="3">E</li>
    </ul>

Updated Browser:
    ---
     B
    ---
     D 
    ---
     E
    ---
     A
    ---
     C
    ---
```

Any suggestions or examples are appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New answer**

I didn't thoroughly read your question, sorry.
Here's another simple approach that moves the items with position absolute and margin-top, the items are outside the list container though so it's not ideal.

```js
function sortList() {
  var list = document.getElementById("listToSort");
  
  var item = list.firstElementChild;
  while(item) {
   item.style.marginTop = ((parseFloat(item.className) - 1) * 20) + "px";
    item = item.nextElementSibling;
  }
  
}
sortList();


// Testing example below
var item1 = document.getElementById("listToSort").getElementsByClassName("1")[0];
var item2 = document.getElementById("listToSort").getElementsByClassName("2")[0];

item1.className = "2";
item2.className = "1";

setTimeout(function() {sortList();},1500);
```

```css
#listToSort>li {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
     -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
      -ms-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
       -o-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
          transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<ul id="listToSort" class="sortedlist">
  <li class="4">A</li>
  <li class="1">B</li>
  <li class="5">C</li>
  <li class="2">D</li>
  <li class="3">E</li>
</ul>
```

**Original answer**

Here's a javascript solution, it iterates all list items until they're in order by moving the lowest scored item to the end and then moving on to the second-lowest scored item etc.

```js
function sortList() {
  var list = document.getElementById("listToSort");

  var listItem = list.firstChild;
  var currentScore = 1;

  while (true) {
    if (listItem.className == currentScore) {
      currentScore++;
      list.appendChild(listItem);
      listItem = list.firstChild;
    } else if (listItem.nextSibling) listItem = listItem.nextSibling;
    else break;
  }
}
sortList();
```

```html
<ul id="listToSort" class="sortedlist">
  <li class="4">A</li>
  <li class="1">B</li>
  <li class="5">C</li>
  <li class="2">D</li>
  <li class="3">E</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Mandera, so seems this approach is physically re-arranging the list children in the DOM object.  I don't think CSS transition will work on this, will it?  How can I apply animations when the "scores" are dynamically updated and the list have to be re-sorted?

Comment: Did you ever see my updated answer @cycotron69?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to sort them. That is manageable through CSS property "`disply: flex`".
Try this

```
ul {display: flex; flex-direction: column;}
```

This makes the list items go vertically down. - After you've used flex, you can use `order` property.

```
ul > li:nth-child(0) {order: 2;}
```

`order: 0` is the default value

Comment: how's the support for "flex", are there alternatives if I need to support older browsers, especially for IE?  Thanks.

Comment: This is the support: http://puu.sh/mu4r8/02dbf6029f.png

Comment: Alternative solution involves custom attributes and more programming with JS. If you can code something like `order` attributes. You can try this: [Custom Attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp).

`<li data-order="1">` HTML
`document.querySelectorAll('ul li')[2].getAttribute('data-order');` JavaScript
Manipulate that.